# React native android animation

Tags: android, animation, react-native, animated

I'm trying to animate the height of a View in react native. The animation is working as expected in iOS but is not working in Android. The animated View seems to always be full height regardless of the animation value. Relevant code is below:

```
var Facets = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      h: new Animated.Value(0),
    };
  },

  _animate: function(newHeight) {
    Animated.timing(this.state.h, {
      duration: 300,
      toValue: newHeight
    }).start();
  },

  render: function() {
    var facetComponents = [];

    if (this.props.shown) {
      this._animate(MAX_HEIGHT);
    }
    else {
      this._animate(0);
    }

    facets.map( (facet, idx) => {
      facetComponents.push(
        <Facet
          key={idx}
          facet={facet}
          filterBy={this.props.filterBy} />);
    });

    return (
      <Animated.View style={{ maxHeight: this.state.h }}>
        {facetComponents}
      </Animated.View>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: Check out this conversation: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4644  . Looks like maxHeight and similar properties may not be 100% stable? Maybe someone else can chime in, but possibly try using height as opposed to maxHeight.

Comment: @NaderDabit, thanks for the heads up. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work either. I had originally been using height instead of maxHeight but it meant that I couldn't get back to an 'auto' height when I animate back to the large size from 0.

Comment: Oh I just realized the maxHeight was a variable and not a property ! :/

Comment: This was part of the problem. If I set maxHeight to a static value it has no effect. However, if I use height instead, 0 seems to not work. Setting to 1 makes it very small but not quite gone. Getting closer!

Answer (score -2):

Try moving your Animated Value out of state:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.h = new Animated.Value(0)
}
```

Then, refer to it as `this.h` as opposed to `this.state.h`

Comment: I keep getting the 'red screen of death' when using this method for some reason.

Cannot read property 'stopTracking' of undefined.

Comment: Would you consider animating the margin-top to bring it in and out of view? I can't seem to get the height to animate either for some reason, even using scaleX and scaleY!

Comment: I'm now using a negative marginTop and am calculating the height of the View using the onLayout event to store the height to use. Not getting quite the effect I wanted but I may just have to live with it. Thanks.